# Tool for visualizing Spring Integration flows

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a Java application which is exposing some web methods. I am using Spring integration to define a flow of these methods. I'm looking for a tool/framework to automatically generate visualization (diagrams) of these flows (something like Swagger). Can you recommend me something? Thank you!

Comment: "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more
This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers." official close vote reason ...

Comment: It is indeed a critical question.   Spring integration doesn't have any visualizer which is needed.  Once the Integration app become big and complication,  such visualizer becomes a life saver.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have a visualizing tool yet (work in progress), but here is a model it can be based on: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#integration-graph.

Here is some article how to use it: https://ordina-jworks.github.io/architecture/2018/01/27/Visualizing-your-Spring-Integration-components-and-flows.html

Here is another one based on Neo4J: https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-visualize-a-spring-integration-graph-with-neo4j-61927ba5bb5a

Comment: Hi, may I ask if there was any progress on this topic ("We don't have a visualizing tool yet (work in progress)") since last May? Thanks!

Comment: No, there is no progress in that area. We don't have enough resources in the team to cover everything and priorities have been shifted as well. This doesn't mean that we are abandoning the effort and, of course, we won't mind some contribution.

Comment: I'd like to help in the development of this tool. Please let me know what is the repo and I can join with you.

Comment: The project is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration. Not sure, though, what is your idea with visualizer of that integration graph, but thank you for suggestion! Here is some another old article about Spring Flo: https://springorama.wordpress.com/2018/04/29/integration-graph-when-using-spring-integration-java-dsl/

Comment: This sample also shows some effort: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/applications/file-split-ftp